# Flushing in the repositories

Tags: java, jpa

In most of the code I see (Spring), it seems no one calls `entityManager.flush()` from a repository. Is there a reason for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason. By default, `flush()` is called automatically before the transaction is committed, or before executing a query whose result might depend on the not-flushed-yet modifications. So an explicit `flush()` is almost never needed.

And it's a good thing to flush as late as possible, because it avoids executing queries in case the transaction is rolled back.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, if your JPA code is correctly enclosed in a transaction, flush is done automatically. If you keep a look at logs during code execution you can see:

- update or create operation are not write to the database until:

  - the end of the session (thus end of transaction); thus batching the SQL commands
  - a 'find' operation is executed (because it must be done on a coherent data set by the DB)
- SQL commands can be reorder to be more efficient

Thus, flush command is useful if you want **explicit** 'flush'.

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.setName(“Pluto”);
entityManager.persist(animal); /* pluto is saved here */

Owner owner = new Owner();
owner.setName(“Mickey”);
animal.setOwner(owner);
entityManager.persist(owner); /* mickey is saved here */

owner.setName(“Minnie”);
entityManager.merge(owner);
animal.setName(“Mickey”);
entityManager.merge(animal);

/* pluto and mickey are updated here, just before the find query */
Query q = entityManager.createQuery(“FROM Animal a”);
```